# Java GUI programmming

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, scope

code gives error of nullpointer exception.....wat to do?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui implements ActionListener{
JButton button;

public Gui(){
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JButton button =new JButton("click me!");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.setSize(270,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Gui();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    button.setText("I've been clicked");
}

}
```

Comment: I think that you need to learn some more about Java before attempting GUI development.

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 12):

```
JButton button =new JButton
```

This creates a **local** variable.
The `button` field is still `null`.

Answer (score 5):

Your field `button` which you reference in your actionPerformed method is never initialized, and is thus null.

You have this button `JButton button =new JButton("click me!");` which you add in your main method, but your actionPerformed is never aware of that.

Change the line to read

`this.button =new JButton("click me!");`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that button is visible only inside the constructor.